# Java. Объясните почему данный пример выводит 11 и 9?

Tags: java

```
public class Prim 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i = 1;
        i = i++ +(( i > 2 )? i++: (i++ * i++)) + i++ ;
        System.out.println(i);
        i = 2;
        i = i++ + (( i > 2 )? i++: (i++ * i++)) + i++ ;
        System.out.println(i);
    }  
}
```

Comment: А что он должен выводить по-вашему?

Comment: Первое число меньше второго изначально. Однако вывод сильно отличается

Comment: а в С++ это UB... в других языках просто на код ревью долго думают...

Comment: Объясните почему именно такой странный вывод 11 и 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Два пункта, которые надо знать:

1. Разбор ведется слева направо
2. i++ - в начале возвращает результат, потом инкрементирует; ++i - инкрементирует и возвращает результат

и всё.

```
i = 2;
i = i++ + (( i > 2 )? i++: (i++ * i++)) + i++ ;
```

- в начале идет i++ - вернули 2 и прибавили 1. В i число 3.
- выполняем действия в скобках: 3 > 2 ? Да, значит идем в место где i++
- i было равно 3, возвращаем его и инкрементируем. i уже равно 4
- осталось сложить 4 и i++.  4 + 4 = 8. Возвращаем его и инкрементируем. 8 + 1 = 9

тоже самое с единицей, только в этот раз во втором пункте будет 2 > 2, вместо 3 > 2. А это явно ложь. Поэтому пойдем не в пункт, где i++, а в пункт, где i++ * i++. Ну а далее по пунктам, описанные в начале.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, почему, например, при `i = 4` выражение `i + i++` будет равно `8`?

Comment: @post_zeew второй пункт в ответе: `i++ - в начале возвращает результат, потом инкрементирует` ............ соответственно в начале сложится 4 + 4 и вернет результат в качестве 8...... а потом только i инкрементирует себя. .... то есть `int i = 4;
  
  System.out.println(i + i++);
  System.out.println(i);`  выведет 8 и 5

Comment: Спасибо! Тут, вроде, понятно. **Сначала выводим** результат на экран, а только **потом инкрементируем**. Другой вопрос: `int i = 4; i = i + i++; System.out.println(i);`. Сначала `i=4`, потом будет `i=i+i=4+4=8`, а потом `i++`, то есть в итоге `i=9`, но оно равно `8`. Почему?

Comment: @post_zeew потому что вы вернули 8 в саму себя же......то есть i уже 8, а не 4. А переменой надо еще инкрементироваться. вот и получается остаточную операцию надо провернуть............ сначала **НЕ  выводим** результат на экран, а **возвращаем результат**...... то есть тут `System.out.println(i + i++)` я i ничему не присваивал, поэтому он вернул результат 8, а i осталась равна 4, как и была... Потому что я её никуда не положил....... а потом 4 инкрементировалась..... в случае же с вашими примерами все как бы держится  в уме и складывается в итоге в ту же переменную %)

Comment: Я понял, благодарю!

Comment: Меня интересует больше как получилось 11 в первом случае

Comment: @vbn i++ = 2...... потом в скобках i++ * i++ = 2 * 2 = 4..........затем инкрементируем 4 + 1 = 5......... затем осталось 5 + i++ = 5 + 5 = 10.............инкрементируем 10 + 1 = 11.......................то, что написано i++ * i++ не значит, что должно быть два инкремента. Просто держится "в уме" что надо инкрементировать i после некой операции........ в данном случае операция умножения.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Вроде инкремент имеет более высокий приоритет

Comment: @vbn Если Вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный, нажав галку слева.